# Do APs ever broadcast 802.11 probe requests?

Tags: network-programming, wifi

I have been messing around with monitoring probe requests to track wi-fi enabled devices. I have a scanner in a set location that I know rarely has people near it 24-7. When I look at the resulting probe requests, it appears that some wifi enabled devices are around almost 24-7, which makes me think this is not really a person with a smartphone.

If there are APs in the area, is it possible I am picking up something from them? I am only collecting probe requests: type 0 (management) subtype 4 (probe request). As far as I can tell, only clients should send probe requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the client (also called station node) keep sending probe requests to scan available APs in it's range. AP will respond with probe response and also it keep sending beacons. But an AP can also send probe requests, if it happens to scan for other APs. You can check the probe requests captured and see the RSSI field(signal strength). RSSI being low indicates the sender is a bit far from your monitor.

Comment: But would an AP ever send a probe request?

Comment: Sorry for wrong info. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Any idea why an AP would ever scan for other APs?

Comment: Does it send probe requests on all the channels?. If that is the case, it must be doing an "off channel" scan, for some reason. Refer [this](http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-is-off-channel-scanning-for-wi-fi-access-points-aps) link.